# Are coupons for Chometz - Chometz?

Tags: food, passover, transactions, chametz-leaven

Are coupons for items which are chometz, chometz themselves? Do they have a status of chometz, or can they be dealt with on Pesach?

For example: Can one acquire coupons for grain cereals on Pesach (of course, intending to purchase those items after Pesach)?

Comment: I heard that in Russia where bread was unpurchasable without "bread ration cards", people would save them throughout Pesach and use them after Pesach. One such person heard (after Pesach that the Lubavitcher Rebbe's father [who was a Rov of Dnepopetrovsk]) that such rations are forbidden so he ripped them all up.

Comment: You mean coupons like "Buy two boxes of Cheerios and Save $1.00"?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah. Was I not clear enough?

Comment: Why would this be a problem? What makes you think they would be chometz?

Answer (score 7):

I do not understand why it would be a problem a coupon is a document which entitles one to a discount,but in no way does it give ownership of that item to the holder of the coupon. The item becomes theirs when purchased which is after peasach.

Answer (score 2):

On Pesach you're only prohibited from possessing a tangible quantity of edible chometz (chometz being exactly what it means, leavened grain product). There is no restriction on non-edible, non-food products, such as advertisements or coupons.  You don't even have to get rid of dishes used to cook chometz, as long as you don't eat food cooked with them on Pesach (as they would possibly acquire the taste of chometz from the dish).

[Further reading](http://www.aish.com/h/pes/l/48970611.html)