# Are coupons for Chometz - Chometz? II

Tags: halacha, passover, transactions, agada-stories-legends, bread

Inspired by [yydl's question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15831/732).

I [read](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1744104/jewish/Memoirs-of-Rebbetzin-Chana-Part-15.htm) that in Russia where bread was unpurchasable without "bread ration cards", people would save them throughout Pesach and use them after Pesach. One such person heard (before Pesach) from the Lubavitcher Rebbe's father (who was a Rov of Dnepopetrovsk) that such rations are forbidden so he ripped them all up. (It also says that the Lubavitcher Rebbe's father used to tear up his cards before Pesach).

What is the prohibition behind owning such ration cards (as in, why are they different than money which can also buy one bread)?

Based on the answers there (and my opinion before finding out the above information), there shouldn't be a problem with owning such vouchers.

So why **is** it forbidden?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without an inside halachic source saying it's assur. Sans that, then it's just a story , which isn't really something you can base halachic reasoning on.

Comment: @YaakovKuperman So understand the question to be saying, "if this is true, what would be the halachic reasoning for it?"

Comment: Maybe 'is there any possible halahic reasoning for this?'... Either way, thats really reading into it :)

Comment: @ Shmuel, this is different than the other question, since there it's a coupon that _could_ be redeemed for a _discount_ towards chametz. By bread rations, the card was worth bread! (davar ha'Gorem l'Lechem!)

Comment: I'm confused. You say "One such person heard... that such **rations** are forbidden so he ripped them [=the ration **cards**] all up" and then ask for "the prohibition behind owning such ration **cards**". [Emphasis supplied in each case.] Maybe the rabbi only meant that the rations themselves are prohibited (as containing lard perhaps) and that's why he ripped up the cards (so no one should be tempted to use them).

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1744104/jewish/Memoirs-of-Rebbetzin-Chana-Part-15.htm

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the story is true, then these people assumed/knew that each ration card not only **entitled** one to some bread, but somehow gave one **ownership** of a ration of bread, even before one picked it up.

Maybe one needs an understanding of Russian "law" at the time to fully comprehend this.