# May Jews own gift cards redeemable for Chametz on Passover

Tags: halacha, passover, transactions, chametz-leaven, orach-chaim

In Halacha, is it prohibited for Jews to own gift cards which can be redeemed for chametz over passover or no? Obviously they are prohibited from using it for chametz, but if there is a gift card for a bakery or store which sells bread do Jews have to get rid of it over Pesach?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15831/are-coupons-for-chometz-chometz

Comment: I don't think this is the same question as asking about a coupon because a gift card is significantly different than a coupon. That being said what makes you think a gift card is different than cash which is also redeemable for chometz?